# Excel VBA for navigation Tabs

Tags: excel

Good morning

I have an excel sheet that has over 40 tabs and by pressing control @ brings up a table of all the tabs i can choose from, can anybody explain how they acheive this to enable me to use on other excel books i have?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce something with Ctrl + @.

The only shortcut near is Ctrl + Shift + @: To apply time formatting in Excel.

I think your question is not for this forum specialized to help about programming.

Comment: sorry  mean control Q

Answer (score 0):

It may be a macro in that workbook with a shortcut key assigned. If so, you can move the macro to your PERSONAL.xlsb workbook.

[image]

Comment: thank you, could you please advise how i can check original document for macro's

Comment: Alt+F8 will open the window in my screenshot, or Alt+F11 will open the VBA editor window